# @angular/material-moment-adapter e moment doesn't find in package.json

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, package.json, angular9

I need to format date in angular materia so I follow [this tutorial](http://brickydev.com/angular-material-datepicker-with-many-custom-date-formats/).

My problem is when I install dependencies. I want put this dependencies into `package.json`, so I do this:

```
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter --save
npm i moment --save
```

The problem after I do that, the package.json doens't have this dependecies. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please check permission of package.json file.

Comment: Run your terminal as admin, and ensure you're placed in the root of your project folder

Comment: @Alex It's probably best to fix the file permissions instead of using a root account to install new dependencies as this may not be secure.